# Converting a 32bit number in a proprietary timestamp with PHP

Tags: php

I have a 32 bit number represented as a HEX string that I need to convert to a timestamp following these rules:

[image: Timestamp specification]

What I want to check is that I'm not doing something glaringly stupid? Does my conversion look sane given the timestamp specification?

I've put together the following code to do this. I know PHP isn't the best for this sort of work but it's part of a larger legacy application all written in PHP.

`$t` is taken from an XML file of readings, one every 5 mins.

```
    // convert the hex string to binary
    // sprintf pads leading zeros
    $binStr = sprintf('%032s', base_convert($t, 16, 2));

    //get a decimal representation so we can use the bitwise operator on it
    // I know I could have converted straight to decimal, but I'm debugging
    $decimal = bindec($binStr);

     // get the first 6 bits
    $min = $decimal & bindec('111111');

    // drop the first 8 bits then apply a mask to the next 5
    $hour = ($decimal >> 8) & bindec('11111');

    // drop the first 15 bits then apply a mask to the next 1
    $daylightSaving = ($decimal >> 15) & 1; 

    // etc
    $day  = ($decimal >> 16) & bindec('11111');      
    $yearLsb  = ($decimal >> 21) & bindec('111');
    $month = ($decimal >> 24) & bindec('1111');
    $yearMsb  = ($decimal >> 28) & bindec('1111');

    Logger::debug(
        $t . " Incoming timestamp converted to  \n" . 
        $binStr . " then converted to  \n" . 
        " Day: " . $day . "\n" . 
        " Month: " . $month . "\n" . 
        " Year: " . $yearMsb . $yearLsb . "\n" . 
        " Hour: " . $hour . "\n" . 
        " Min: " . $min . "\n" . 
        " Daylight saving: ". $daylightSaving
    );
```

The output for the last entry in the file is:

```
2DAC1B0A Incoming timestamp converted to
00101101101011000001101100001010 then converted to
 Day: 12
 Month: 13
 Year: 25
 Hour: 27
 Min: 10
 Daylight saving: 0
```

I know the file was created at 11:25am on the 12th Nov 2013, the readings are for 11:10 to 11:25 with the last one in the file being the 11:10am one.

The mins match those in the file I get 10 through 25 in 5 min increments. The day is also accurate if I run it against other files.

There's a chance that the equipment manufacturer who wants us to purchase some expensive software to do this parsing has munged the timetamp specification but that being an option I've played with lots of possible combinations in that 32bit integer and I can't see how I can get all the numbers I require from the supplied timestamps.

Comment: Converting to a string containing "0"s and "1"s falls on the wrong side of "sane". Use bitwise operations instead.

Comment: Maybe better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams not sure what you mean. The bin conversion was for debugging only and the bindec() for the mask was for human readability. The output is the same regardless. Unless you mean something else? I've posted this over onto code review with the decimal version: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37051/converting-a-32bit-number-in-a-proprietary-timestamp-with-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a C code and converted it to PHP. The results are a bit different but also obviously wrong. But perhaps that helps you.

The C code you find [here](http://www.rscada.se/websvn/filedetails.php?repname=FreeSCADA+Open+Source+Repository&path=%2Flibmbus-0.7%2Fmbus%2Fmbus-protocol.c). Search for `Compound CP32`. (There are no line numbers)

```
$hex = 0x2DAC1B0A;
$dt0 = $hex & 0xff;
$dt1 = ($hex >> 8) & 0xff;
$dt2 = ($hex >> 16) & 0xff;
$dt3 = ($hex >> 24) & 0xff;

$min = $dt0 & 0x3F;
$hour  = $dt1 & 0x1F;
$day  = $dt2 & 0x1F;
$mon   = ($dt3 & 0x0F) - 1;
$year  = (($dt2 & 0xE0) >> 5) | (($dt3 & 0xF0) >> 1);
$dayLightSaving = ($dt1 & 0x80) ? 1 : 0;

echo $min.'<br>'; // 10
echo $hour.'<br>'; // 27
echo $day.'<br>'; // 12
echo $mon.'<br>'; // 12
echo $year.'<br>'; // 21
echo $dayLightSaving; // 0
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I'll check the C out and see if it helps.

Comment: I'm marking this as an answer: for pointing me at the libmbus source code (which helps me out in other areas not relating to the question) and for allowing me to validate my code above.

Answer (score 0):

The year is decoded (or rather, displayed) incorrectly:

```
" Year: " . $yearMsb . $yearLsb . "\n" .
```

This looks like you assume the year to be in BCD.

To calculate the correct year you should do:

```
$year = $yearLSB | ($yearMSB << 3);
```

Note that EN 13757 (the MBUS standard you try to decode) also defines a "hundred year" (century) field:

```
$hy = ($decimal >> 13) & 0x03;
$year = 1900 + 100 * $hy + $year;

if ($year < 1980)
  $year += 100;
```

The `if` corrects timestamps of older meters, as even suggested by the standard itself.

I don't see the reason for the wrong *hour*, though, as `($hour >> 8) & 0x1F` should be correct. Same applies for the rest of the fields. I guess the value of `$decimal` itself does not match the value sent by the meter. Try to avoid converting to/from stings, perhaps.